# React - 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property in reader.onload

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, reader

When I run code below

console display:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of undefined
```

but the test code can display:

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.component).innerText = 'ddd';
```

What's problem?

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
  console.log('onload: ' + e.target.result);
  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.component).innerText = e.target.result;                   
}

reader.onerror = function(stuff) {
    console.log("error", stuff);
    console.log (stuff.getMessage());
}

ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.component).innerText = 'ddd';
console.log('readAsText:' + reader.readAsText(data[0]));
```

Comment: The `onload` function has the wrong `this`, which is why you're getting the error

Comment: Thanks! How can i modify?
My component named  'EditArea'
but i put this to EditArea still error

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: it's work!! thanks very much:)